# Total amount of columns in mySQL !

Tags: sql, mysql

i have this sql :

```
SELECT * , (
xnum * xprice
) AS amount, SUM( xnum * xprice ) AS total
FROM xxbasket
LEFT JOIN xxsubproduct
USING ( xsubproduct_id )
LEFT JOIN xxcolor
USING ( xcolor_id )
WHERE xuserid = '3'
```

when i use SUM( xnum * xprice ) AS total it's gives me only one row , but when i remove this SUM( xnum * xprice ) it's give me all rows

My question is how can i get sum ? while i need all rows from query ?!

Comment: It is not perfectly clear by it seems like you are trying to do two things with one query. Either brake it into two queries or write two sub-queries and then do a JOIN.

Comment: @mfx i don't know how to create sub queries could you Please Explain How To Create Sub Querys and Join them together ?!

Comment: ok , i break into 2 subqueries like this SELECT * , (
xnum * xprice
) AS amount, xxcolor.xcode AS color, xxsubproduct.xcode AS productcode, (

SELECT SUM( xnum * xprice )
FROM xxbasket
WHERE xuserid = '3'
) AS total
FROM xxbasket
LEFT JOIN xxsubproduct
USING ( xsubproduct_id )
LEFT JOIN xxcolor
USING ( xcolor_id )
WHERE xuserid = '3' it's now working but numbers are irrelevant !

Answer (score 2):

Sum is a function where the sum of your value (xnum * xprice) over all selected rows is calculated. The result is one row.

If you want to calculate the sum of multiple groups of rows, you may use the GROUP BY clause, which groups columns to groups (e.g. GROUP BY userid instead of your where clause would calculate  SUM(xnum * xprice) for all users)

Answer (score 0):

The SUM() function is an aggregate operator.  The select it is associated with can no longer return individual rows, only information about groups of rows.

But you could return the sum in a subquery.  Here's an example, assuming the xprice column is in the xxsubproduct table:

```
SELECT *, 
    xnum * xprice AS amount, 
    (   select sum(xnum * xprice)
        FROM xxbasket
        LEFT JOIN xxsubproduct USING xsubproduct_id
        WHERE xuserid = '3'
    ) as total
FROM xxbasket
LEFT JOIN xxsubproduct USING xsubproduct_id
LEFT JOIN xxcolor USING xcolor_id
WHERE xuserid = '3'
```